# How do I add a list of objects (structs) to a YAML file and unmarshal it in Go?

Tags: go, yaml, unmarshalling

I am experiencing **a problem with unmarshalling a YAML file in Go, comprising an attribute that is a list of objects/maps**. Here is the context. (This might not necessarily be a Go-specific problem, something's wrong with my YAML specification maybe)

The schema of something I would like to represent via a YAML looks like the following.

```
type A struct {
    b  []B `json:"a,omitempty" yaml:"b,omitempty"`
}

type B struct {
    c C `json:"c,omitempty" yaml:"c,omitempty"`
    d string `json:"d" yaml:"d"`
}

type C struct {
    e bool `json:"e" yaml:"e"`
    f *F `json:"f" yaml:"f"`
}

type F struct {
    g []G `json:"g,omitempty" yaml:"g,omitempty"`
    h string `json:"h,omitempty" yaml:"h,omitempty"`
    i []I `json:"i,omitempty" yaml:"i,omitempty"`
    j string `json:"j,omitempty" yaml:"j,omitempty"`
}

type G struct {
    g1 string `json:"g1,omitempty" yaml:"g1,omitempty"`
    g2 string `json:"g2,omitempty" yaml:"g2,omitempty"`
}

type I struct {
    i1 string `json:"i1,omitempty" yaml:"i1,omitempty"`
    i2 string `json:"i2,omitempty" yaml:"i2,omitempty"`
}
```

Before some recent changes made to the above definition of types, variables `g` and `i` defined in the struct `F` were not lists (variable `g` was of type `G` and not `[]G`; and similarly with `i`), and with a basic YAML unmarshal function that looked like the following,

```
var a A

// someFile is the YAML file
content, err := os.ReadFile(someFile)
if err != nil {
    return a, err
}
err = yaml.Unmarshal(content, &a)
if err != nil {
    return a, err
}

return a, nil
```

unmarshalling a YAML file looking like this worked successfully.

```
b:
  - c:
      e: true
      f:
        g:
          g1: sample-g1-string-one
          g2: sample-g2-string-one
        h: sample-h-string-one
        i:
          i1: sample-i1-string-one
          i2: sample-i2-string-one
        j: sample-j-string-one
    d: sample-d-string-one
  - c:
      e: false
      f:
        g:
          g1: sample-g1-string-two
          g2: sample-g2-string-two
        h: sample-h-string-two
        i:
          i1: sample-i1-string-two
          i2: sample-i2-string-two
        j: sample-j-string-two
    d: sample-d-string-two
```

However, now that in the struct `f`, variable `g` is now a list of `G` (`[]G`) and similarly variable `i` is of type `[]I`, I would need to have variables `g` as a list, in which each element would contain `g1` and `g2`; similarly, with `i`. When I try doing so with the following YAML

```
b:
  - c:
      e: true
      f:
        - g:
             g1: sample-g1-string-one
             g2: sample-g2-string-one
        - g:
             g1: sample-g1-string-one-two
             g2: sample-g2-string-one-two
        h: sample-h-string-one
        - i:
             i1: sample-i1-string-one
             i2: sample-i2-string-one
        - i:
             i1: sample-i1-string-one-two
             i2: sample-i2-string-one-two
        j: sample-j-string-one
    d: sample-d-string-one
```

I see an unmarshal error that says

```
line XX: cannot unmarshal !!seq into F
```

If I modify the YAML to look like the following (assuming this could be the right format, based on what I'm doing with `-c`s in the YAML)

```
b:
  - c:
      e: true
      f:
        g:
          - g1: sample-g1-string-one
            g2: sample-g2-string-one
          - g1: sample-g1-string-one-two
            g2: sample-g2-string-one-two
        h: sample-h-string-one
        i:
          - i1: sample-i1-string-one
            i2: sample-i2-string-one
          - i1: sample-i1-string-one-two
            i2: sample-i2-string-one-two
        j: sample-j-string-one
    d: sample-d-string-one
  - c:
      e: false
      f:
        g:
          g1: sample-g1-string-two
          g2: sample-g2-string-two
        h: sample-h-string-two
        i:
          i1: sample-i1-string-two
          i2: sample-i2-string-two
        j: sample-j-string-two
    d: sample-d-string-two
```

This ends up with two errors

```
line XX: cannot unmarshal !!seq into G
line YY: cannot unmarshal !!seq into I
```

Could there be a problem with the way I'm defining these attributes in the YAML? I would like to work this out through the YAML as I cannot modify the code in the project at the moment - would like any help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must export your fields. For the rest: Get your types and YAML structure right (your examples are too complicated for a quick check).

Comment: Your last YAML document is close, but you forgot to turn g and i into lists in the second c.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, friends. I'm relatively new to programming, and would need more of your inputs.

Volker - can you please give me a little more idea on what exactly you mean by exporting fields? One line will do, I'll look the rest up :)


@Peter - how would I turn g and i into lists in a YAML file?

Comment: Exported identifiers are covered in the Tour of Go.

Comment: Prefix g1 and i1 with a -, just like you did above. It may be easier to read if you use JSON encoding (every valid JSON document is also a valid YAML document, so you don't have to change the parser).